# Core Data Error --- NSManagedObjectModel issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have set up the core data stack and i tried to test and build the project.  However, i received the error as:

[image]

After I did the research, the potential error could be: the file's model file's name is different with the name in the Core Data Stack. But it still crashes as before.

```
#pragma mark - Core Data stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"RunMaster"        withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return _managedObjectModel;
}


 - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
 if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]      URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"RunMaster.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]    URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have a file named RunMaster

Comment: @DipankarDas well, the complier error normally because the model file name is not matched with the core data stack, however I checked over and over again, the name is matched

Comment: make sure it is in the Copy bundle ressources.

Comment: @DipankarDas how to confirm it is in the copy bundle resources

Comment: @DipankarDas I checked it, it is in the copy bundle resources

Answer (score 0):

Do you have made change on data structure ? new scheme ? entity ?

for quick test uninstall application and install it again if that work again

then you should implement the update of your data struct or change the storage name / migrate data...

Your error suggest a nil URL in modelURL

Comment: No, I did not change any data structure and i quickly test the application by reset the the simulator. It still crashes.